# Cookies will not work

Tags: php, cookies, web-deployment

Why is the value not deleted?
When you refresh the page, they are deleted, if you press "back" they are resumed

```
<?php
//delete
setcookie("loginCouchSite","",time()-3600);
setcookie("passCouchSite","",time()-3600);
$login = $_COOKIE['loginCouchSite'];
$pass = $_COOKIE['passCouchSite'];
    echo"$login,$pass";//VALUE NOT DELETE!
?>
```

Comment: Make sure no characters before `<?php`

Comment: i change cookies to session and all worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because pressing "back" does not send a new request to the server. Therefore this php code isnt executed and the client doesnt know that he should set the cookies to "".

Comment: but how to send a request to the server to change the value?

Comment: this code is in exit.php

Comment: link "EXIT" <a href="exit.php">Exit</a>

Comment: I need to delete the values ​​at the exit altogether

Comment: because the client clicks "back" after the exit and still remains in the account

Comment: Sending to home does not help

Comment: ok, i make video and send youtube ok?

Comment: do I change the cookies in a session?

Comment: user login -> make random string and "kay" add in DB.
user return -> check user cookie "kay" and DB "kay". 
user exit -> delete "kay" in DB.
Yes?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9DHNjWMysNU&feature=youtu.be

Comment: thx, friend. I change cookies to session and all worked.